# Ant - Verify if two binaries (jar) are strictly equals

Tags: ant

I am using Ant 1.9.4.
I have two jar files and I would like to know if they are strictly equals.
Of course not only the name but every file in it.
My guess would be to have like a MD5 checker on something like that but I don't know if it is possible via ant.

Thank you for your help,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant core provides a [checksum task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html) :

```
Generates checksum for files. This task can also be used to perform checksum verifications.
```

May be used with conditon to make your build fail if binaries are not equal, f.e. :

```
<checksum file="path/to/foo.jar" property="fooMD5"/>

<fail message="Binaries not equal !!">
 <condition>
  <not>
   <checksum file="path/to/fooo.jar" property="${fooMD5}"/>
  </not>
 </condition>
</fail>
```

There are also `filesmatch` and `resourcesmatch` conditions for file compare, see [ant manual conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

Comment: Thanksthat will definitely help.